# Fusioncharts on C# with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, fusioncharts

I know fusioncharts only use XML/JSON as entries, but, is there a way i can use my entity model with fusioncharts? , or should i need to create the xml from my database and send it to fusioncharts?.

for example, i could try something like this...

```
StringBuilder xmlData = new StringBuilder();
xmlData.Append ("<set label='.Entity.Name.' value='.Entity.Value.' />");
```

On a Foreach, to build the xml for fusioncharts, but, i want to know if there's an easy way to do this, **is there a way that the entity framework gives me the XML or Fusioncharts could read an Object or List?**.

I'm talking about a web project. C#.NET & ASP.NET.

Easiest way to connect Fusioncharts with an Entity Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionChart can only parse/read XML or JSON. So for any data sources you'll have to create the XML/JSON from that data source. The steps you are following is correct:

```
StringBuilder xmlData = new StringBuilder();
xmlData.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' />", Entity.Name, Entity.Value);
```